# Error: Value of property LoadBalancerAttributes must be of type List

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Error: Value of property LoadBalancerAttributes must be of type List

I followed cloud formation documentation and set the Attributes but still I am getting error

Can anyone know the issue and where I went wrong?

how can fix the template

````
Resources:

  IAPILoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref IAPIBlueTargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref IAPILoadBalancer
      Port: !Ref LoadBalancerPort
      Protocol: TCP
  IAPILoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        access_logs.s3.bucket: xxxxxxxx
        access_logs.s3.prefix: xxxxxxxx
        access_logs.s3.enabled: false
        deletion_protection.enabled: fasle
      Name: NLB
      Scheme: internal
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PrivateRailA
        - !Ref PrivateRailB
      Type: network
      Tags:
        - Key: "platform_name"
          Value: "nx"```
````

Answer (score 3):

[LoadBalancerAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-loadbalancerattributes) should have different form.

Please have a look at the following:

```
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: access_logs.s3.bucket
          Value: xxxxxxxx
        - Key: access_logs.s3.prefix
          Value: xxxx
        - Key: access_logs.s3.enabled
          Value: false
        - Key: deletion_protection.enabled
          Value: false
```